# On Fri morning I was racing to work and took usual NYC train from Princeton and

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

I found a piece of paper with these scribbled on it

Dark Thunder.   X  P X ...with P circled

Silver Lightning.  X X X...

What could those X s possibly represent?

Hint 1: Given yesterday

Hint 2: It is surprising that nobody responded, considering that

> It is as simply as one, two, three.

Hint 3

> Racing..1,2,3 positions.

Comment: Clue is in the title

Comment: Hint 3 given...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to do with horse races?  A betting slip?  A result list?  I know that a track will have multiple races on the same day, but don't know if the same horse will run multiple times.  If so, then it could be how the two horses did in the three races: "W" for win, "P" for place, or "X" for later.

Comment: You almost got it..you need to get the last one

Comment: X would indicate the position of the horse in the race.

Comment: There is a name for third position..like win..place...?

Answer (score -1):

> W..P..S..in horse racing lingo..win..place..show 1,2,3